# How to play notification sound in mobile website

Tags: swift, mobile, web, webview, push

I have a WebView mobile application. So I use a website embbeded in this application.
I'm searching a way to play sound notifications in mobile `website` when the device screen is in `locked mode`.
How can I do this ?

I heard that this is called as **Specific Push** or **Web Push** but I couldn't find a code for this in anywhere.

**Update 1**
I'm trying with Swift and Xamarin.

**Update 2**
I learned [from here](https://onesignal.com/blog/when-will-web-push-be-supported-in-ios/) that currently Web Push is not supported by Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send push notifications you can use something like [onesignal.com](https://onesignal.com/) or create your own push server. If you use Phonegap you can send local notification, but it will only work if your app is running while phone is in sleep mode.

Comment: But can I also use the notifications with sound in that site?

Comment: have you tried this? [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/)

Comment: No I didn't. I'm new in mobile programming.

Comment: How can I integrate onesignal.com service to my project? Could you give me some code for this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is code example on their site and they are not only one who can provide push notifications. I haven't used push services myself, it just one of the options of how you can solve your problem.

Comment: Okey I will try this and will inform here.

Comment: I'm trying Onesignal com but when created the application on the site, it requested a Google API key and when I wanted to get it from its link, Google requested me an Android package name. But currently I'm trying for IOS :/ What do I have to do?

Comment: As I understood web push is just for web-sites and not for mobile applications. Applications must use Apple Push Notification Service to sent notifications.

Comment: But I'm using webview, so trying on a website. Please correct me if I'm misundertanding something.

Comment: At the end you will get an APP not web site. You have 2 options, local notifications or remote (Push). If you need "push" you can use onesignal or something similar, if you choose local than you have to program. And link to xamarin I gave you before will explain how to do that.

Comment: Yes. Xamarin will translate your code to native to use notifications.

Comment: Do you say, if I use Xamarin's web push in a webview project, Xamarin will translate it to native, although the project is a webview project? This is great. So I think Swift may do this, too...

Comment: With Xamarin you can build app for Android and iOS, but Swift is for iOS only.